# if $r,s$ are rational numbers, then $r+s\sqrt2$ is irrational unless $s=0$?

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, rational-numbers

> if $r,s$ are rational numbers, Prove $r+s\sqrt2$ is irrational unless $s=0$?

I need to prove this simple question, but not sure if my method is acceptable

I'm trying to prove it by contradiction, Suppose $r+s\sqrt2 = a$, where $a$ is a rational number. Then by given $s$ not equal to $0$, we can say $\sqrt2 = \frac{a-r}{s}$ where $\frac{a-r}{s}$ is a rational number because $a,r,s$ are rational numbers, hence it must be rational, and we have a contradiction.

Did i do this correctly??

Comment: it's perfect. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @dREaM woah thats a relief, I thought i did it okay but there was a discussion among classmates whether this is a right method or not so!

Comment: I personally wouldn't have done it like that, but it is better than what I would have done initially.

Comment: I would love to see other methods because this is the only way I could think of @dREaM

Comment: @Allie  Though I'm sure there are other methods, I'm pretty sure your way is canonical; it's what first came to my mind as well.

Comment: Correct as can be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Please don't upvote - just adding answer so question not stuck in unanswered state forever]

As per the numerous comments, your proof is correct.